# Working on Homotopy Equivalent

Tags: homotopy-theory

Suppose I have spaces $X_{0}, X_{1},Y_{0},Y_{1}$ and $X_{0}$ is homotopy equivalent to $Y_{0}$ and $X_{1}$ is homotopy equivalent to $Y_{1}$.

I would like to show that $X_{0}$ x $X_{1} $ is homotopy equivalent to $Y_{0}$ x $Y_{1} $.

How do I approach this statement? I am fresh new to this topic so any input will be greatly appreciated.
Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since $X_0 \simeq Y_0$ and $X_1 \simeq Y_1$, there are two pairs of functions
$$X_0 \overset{f_0}{\underset{g_0}{\rightleftarrows}} Y_0 \quad \text{and} \quad X_1 \overset{f_1}{\underset{g_1}{\rightleftarrows}} Y_1$$
such that the relevant composites are homotopic to the relevant identities.

From these functions, you can construct functions
$$X_0 \times X_1 \overset{f}{\underset{g}{\rightleftarrows}} Y_0 \times Y_1$$
where $f$ and $g$ are defined by
$$f(x_0,x_1) = (f_0(x_0),f_1(x_1)) \quad \text{and} \quad g(y_0,y_1)=(g_0(y_0),g_1(y_1))$$
for all $x_0,x_1,y_0,y_1$.

You need to check that $g \circ f \sim \mathrm{id}_{X_0 \times X_1}$ and $f \circ g \sim \mathrm{id}_{Y_0 \times Y_1}$.

In a similar way to how we constructed $f$ and $g$ from $f_0,f_1,g_0,g_1$, you can construct the two desired homotopies from the homotopies
$$g_0 \circ f_0 \sim \mathrm{id}_{X_0}, \quad g_1 \circ f_1 \sim \mathrm{id}_{X_1}, \quad f_0 \circ g_0 \sim \mathrm{id}_{Y_0} \quad \text{and} \quad f_1 \circ g_1 \sim \mathrm{id}_{Y_1}$$
I'll leave you to construct these homotopies.

Comment: Hi, by definition of an equivalence relation, I need to check: reflexive, symmetric and transitive. Right?

Comment: Hugh: Your question is asking about proving that something is a homotopy equivalence of spaces, not that something is an equivalence relation. (Homotopy equivalence *is* an equivalence relation, but that's besides the point.)

Comment: So let me try. Consider $(f \circ g)(y_{0},y_{1}) = f(g_{0}(y_{0}),g_{1}(y_{1})) = f(x_{0},x_{1})$ which is the identity of $Y_{0} \times Y_{1}$. Am I right?

Comment: @Hugh: No, $(f \circ g)(y_0,y_1) = (f_0(g_0(y_0)),f_1(g_1(y_1)))$, which in general need not be equal to $(y_0,y_1)$. The composite $f \circ g$ needs to be *homotopic* to the identity on $Y_0 \times Y_1$. To prove this is the case, you need to construct a homotopy $f \circ g \sim \mathrm{id}_{Y_0 \times Y_1}$ using the homotopies $f_0 \circ g_0 \sim \mathrm{id}_{Y_0}$ and $f_1 \circ g_1 \sim \mathrm{id}_{Y_1}$.

Comment: My textbook, topology by James Munkres defines that let X, Y be topological spaces and $f,g: X \rightarrow Y$ be continuous functions. We say f is homotopic to g if there exists a continuous function $H: X \times I \rightarrow Y$ such that H restricted to $X \times \{0\} = f$ and H restricted to $X \times \{1\} = g.$ Then he gives an example of a homotopic equivalence: $\mathbb{R}^{n}$ is homotopic equivalence to a single point {0}. The composite $f \circ g$ looks like what I did above.  This process has not been clear to me so far. I am sorry. I know I am not good at topology.

Comment: You know that $f_0 \circ g_0 \sim \mathrm{id}_{Y_0}$, and so there exists $H_0 : Y_0 \times I \to Y_0$ such that $H_0 |_{Y_0 \times \{0\}} = g_0 \circ f_0$ and $H_0 |_{Y_0 \times \{1\}} = \mathrm{id}_{Y_0}$. Likewise there's $H_1 : Y_1 \times I \to Y_1$ which is a homotopy $f_1 \circ g_1 \sim \mathrm{id}_{Y_1}$. You now need to define a homotopy $H : (Y_0 \times Y_1) \times I \to Y_0 \times Y_1$ such that $H |_{(Y_0 \times Y_1) \times \{ 0 \}} = f \circ g$ and $H |_{(Y_0 \times Y_1) \times \{1\}} = \mathrm{id}_{Y_0 \times Y_1}$. And then repeat all this to prove $g \circ f \sim \mathrm{id}$.

Comment: I was thinking about that last night too. Thank you! By the way, when we say the $id_{Y_{0} \times Y_{1}}$, does it mean it is also $Y_{0} \times Y_{1}$? Also, $f \circ g$ by construction above means that  $(f \circ g)(y_{0},y_{1})=(f_{0}(g_{0}(y_{0})),f_{1}(g_{1}(y_{1})))$ and since $g_{0}(y_{0}) = x_{0}, g_{1}(y_{1}) = x_{1}$, then why did you say in general it is not equal to $(y_{0},y_{1})$?

Answer (score -1):

acord your homotopy you to functions f0 and f1 and g0 g1 and g0(f0) in X0 and(g1(f1)) in X1 are nullhomotopys. I try to take the function f:=(f0,f1) and g:=(g0,g1) so g(f)=(g0(f0),g1(f1)) is nullhomotopy in X0*X1.